# Sending email from inside a plugin using PHP PEAR

Tags: plugins, php, email

I have a plugin that I have developed, part of this plugin will hopefully to send emails with attachments. Before I started with Wordpress I did something similar with PHP using the PEAR class as you can send MIME emails.

I was wondering if it was possible to use the PEAR class in a Wordpress plugin or should I go down an alternative route?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [wp_mail on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail). This will do everything you need, and it's "the wordpress way". There are also particular controls for attachments.

Basic usage is:
`<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>`